# CPU recomendation for animator`s computer

Tags: processor, pc, rendering

I am helping my brother build a budget computer for his studies as animator.

Right now the budget is very low, so I opted to buy a good CPU to futureproof any of his needs and buy a better graphics card in future upgrade.

I did some research and I came up with the following processors:
**AMD Ryzen 7 2700X**
**AMD Ryzen 5 3600**

Which do you think is the most suitable for this build.

Comment: Try looking at benchmarks over at Puget Systems - they do a lot of those for graphics and related stuff, both rendering engines and apps like Adobe Premiere or AE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AMD Ryzen™ 5 3600**

- socket AM4
- 6-cores, 12-threads
- base clock 3.6ghz, boost clock 4.2 ghz
- cache: L1 = 384kb, L2=3mb, L3 = 32MB
- TDP 65 watt
- unlocked, over clockable
- https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-3600
- current pricing $120 - $170

**AMD Ryzen™ 7 2700X**

- socket AM4
- 8-cores, 16 threads
- base clock 3.7 ghz, boost clock 4.3 ghz
- cache: L1=768kb, L2=4mb, L3=16MB
- TDP 105 watt
- unlocked, over clockable
- https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-2700x
- current pricing $140 - $170

both CPU's are on the same socket, the ryzen 7 2700X is the better based on more cores **and** higher frequencies, and higher L1 and L2 cache.  Any software that is cpu based will run faster on the r7-2700x compared to the r5-3600.  There is basically no price difference.  Total Dissipated Power of 65 watt versus 105 watt is not a deciding factor... if anything the higher wattage of the r7 further proves it can do more work that the r5.

Comment: I decided to go with this approach because of the limited budget. In Greece where I live both CPUs are still very price. The ryzen 7 2700X costs 221$ and the ryzen 5 3600X costs 290$. Although the later is a clear choice the extra 70$ is a restrictive factor.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go for **AMD Ryzen 5 3600**

=> `Ryzen 5 3600` is 3rd generation of AMD's processors and `Ryzen 7 2700X` is second generation.

=> `Ryzen 5 3600` is based on latest **7nm** processor and `Ryzen 7 2700X` is based on **12nm**

=> `Ryzen 5 3600` is much more recent than `Ryzen 7 2700X`

=> `Ryzen 5 3600` requires **65W** and `Ryzen 7 2700X` requires **105W** to operate

**You can visit the link below to check the best review and comparison of both processors**

[Ryzen 5 3600 vs Ryzen 7 2700X](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/AMD-Ryzen-7-2700X-vs-AMD-Ryzen-5-3600/3958vs4040)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the **Ryzen 5 3600** for these reasons:

- The 3600 has faster *single core* performance, and almost matches the *multi core* performance of the Ryzen 7 2700X because of that. The Ryzen 7 2700X does a little better in [CPU rendering benchmarks](https://www.techpowerup.com/review/amd-ryzen-5-3600/6.html) but you *should* be using a GPU for rendering anyways. That would make this small advantage irrelevant.
- The CPU needs only 65W, which is a ~40% power reduction over the 2700X.
  That means the included CPU cooler will be adequate, and the system will not be as noisy.
- The 3600 has an [improved architecture](https://www.anandtech.com/show/14525/amd-zen-2-microarchitecture-analysis-ryzen-3000-and-epyc-rome) that provides several advantages over the 2700X:

  - PCIe 4.0 Support
  - Infinity Fabric 2 - The DDR frequency no longer determines the CPU's internal fabric speed. Pairing a 2700X with cheap DDR4 RAM will have a greater consequence on overall performance than a 3600 with the same RAM would.
  - Significantly improved [AVX2](https://www.anandtech.com/show/14525/amd-zen-2-microarchitecture-analysis-ryzen-3000-and-epyc-rome/9) capabilties.
    This instruction set is used in a lot of number-crunching applications, including video encoding. (Which an animator will be doing every time they export a video!)

My recommendation is based on both of these CPUs being the same price though. They are close enough in performance that whichever is less expensive is probably the better *value*.